# Counting items in txt file with Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, count, bioinformatics, contains

I have following txt file (only a fragment is given)

```
     ## DISTANCE : Shortest distance from variant to transcript
## a lot of comments here
    ## STRAND : Strand of the feature (1/-1)
    ## FLAGS : Transcript quality flags
    #Uploaded_variation     Location        Allele  Gene    Feature Feature_type    Consequence     cDNA_position   CDS_position    Protein_position        Amino_acids     Codons  Existing_variation      Extra
    chr1_69270_A/G  chr1:69270      G       ENSG00000186092 ENST00000335137 Transcript      upstream_gene_variant      216     180     60      S       tcA/tcG -       IMPACT=LOW;STRAND=1
    chr1_69270_A/G  chr1:69270      G       ENSG00000186092 ENST00000641515 Transcript      intron_variant      303     243     81      S       tcA/tcG -       IMPACT=LOW;STRAND=1
    chr1_69511_A/G  chr1:69511      G       ENSG00000186092 ENST00000335137 Transcript      upstream_gene_variant        457     421     141     T/A     Aca/Gca -       IMPACT=MODERATE;STRAND=1
```

with many unknown various ENSG numbers, such as ENSG00000187583, etc. The count of integers in each ENSG string is 11.

I have to count how many intron_variant and upstream_gene_variant contains each gene (ENSGxxx).
and output it to csv file.

I use dictionary for this purpose. i tried to write this code, but not sure about correct syntax.
The logics should be: if these 11 numbers are not in dictionary, it should be added with value 1. If they already are in dictionary, value should be changed to x + 1. I currently have this code, but I am not really Python programmer, and not sure about correct syntax.

```
    with open(file, 'rt') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        Count = 0
        d = {}
        for line in data:
            if line[0] == "#":
                output.write(line)
            if line.__contains__('ENSG'): 
                d[line.split('ENSG')[1][0:11]]=1
                if 1 in d:
                    d=1
                else:
                    Count += 1
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your question about this code? The Python interpreter will tell you if the syntax is correct. Does it do what you want? If not, what is it doing wrong?

Comment: It just works with the example you provided. `4
{'00000187961': 1, '00000187583': 1}` Count = 4. Is this OK?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    ensg = []
    for line in fp:
        idx = line.find('ENSG')
        if not line.startswith('#') and idx != -1:
            ensg.append(line[idx+4:idx+15])
count = Counter(ensg)
```

```
>>> count
Counter({'00000187961': 2, '00000187583': 2})
```

**Update**

> I need to know how many ENGs contain "intron_variant" and "upstream_gene_variant"

Use regex to extract desired patterns:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

PAT_ENSG = r'ENSG(?P<ensg>\d{11})'
PAT_VARIANT = r'(?P<variant>intron_variant|upstream_gene_variant)'

PATTERN = re.compile(fr'{PAT_ENSG}.*\b{PAT_VARIANT}\b')

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    ensg = []
    for line in fp:
        sre = PATTERN.search(line)
        if not line.startswith('#') and sre:
            ensg.append(sre.groups())
    count = Counter(ensg)
```

Output:

```
>>> count
Counter({('00000186092', 'upstream_gene_variant'): 2,
         ('00000186092', 'intron_variant'): 1})
```

Comment: Thank you! but now it outputs count of all ENSG IDS, but need to know how many ENGs contain "intron_variant" and "upstream_gene_variant"

Comment: I propose you to post the expected outcome of your sample. It will be easier for me.

Comment: Thank you! Actually the desired result was - to count how many upstream_gene_variant or intron_variant there are for each gene?

Comment: @user15480777. I updated my answer. Can you check my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another interpretation of your requirement:-

I have modified your sample data such that the first ENG value is ENSG00000187971 to highlight how this works.

```
D = {}

with open('eng.txt') as eng:
    for line in eng:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            t = line.split()
            V = t[6]
            E = t[3]
            if not V in D:
                D[V] = {}
            if not E in D[V]:
                D[V][E] = 1
            else:
                D[V][E] += 1
print(D)
```

The output of this is:-

{'intron_variant': {'ENSG00000187971': 1, 'ENSG00000187961': 1}, 'upstream_gene_variant': {'ENSG00000187583': 2}}

So what you have now is a dictionary keyed by variant. Each variant has its own dictionary keyed by the ENSG values and a count of occurrences of each ENSG value

Comment: Hello,
i tried this, but now get following:
"IndexError: list index out of range" . 
I use Python 3

Comment: Your data must differ either in content or structure from the sample you originally posted

Comment: Hello, I updated sample. There are differences in header

Comment: This will work with your data. You've just added comment lines to your sample which this code accounts for